# SQL query to select all tuples that do not have a specific attribute at all

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (shown below) that maps users to the fruits that they like. This table is a result of a a complicated `SELECT` statement, and now I am left with specifying the `WHERE` condition.

I would like to select all users that do not like the fruit "Orange" at all.

| U.id | F.fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 1 | Orange |
| 1 | Orange |
| 2 | Mango |
| 3 | Mango |
| 4 | Mango |
| 4 | Grapes |
| 5 | Apple |
| 5 | Orange |
| 6 | NULL |

The resulting table should consist of users `2, 3, 4, 6`, because users `1` and `5` have tuples that map them to "Oranges".

I am not allowed to use any sub-queries (make another `SELECT` statement). I am not sure how to do this given these restrictions, and I was not sure of how to google search for SQL queries for this specific situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to select all users that do not like the fruit "Orange" at all.

Assuming you have a table of users, I would suggest `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from <your query here> q
                  where q.user_id = u.user_id and q.fruit = 'orange'
                 );
```

Alternatively, you could aggregate, but this would only return users in your query:

```
select user_id
from <your query here>
group by user_id
having count(*) filter (where fruit = 'orange') = 0;
```

Or, if you showed the query, there might be other solutions as well.

Comment: I am not allowed to make any sub queries. I am trying to do some practice questions, and the solution you've provided is actually a part of the question, I'm supposed to adapt your solution into one where I cannot use any sub queries.

Comment: Thank you so much! sorry it took awhile for the edit to load properly. This solution works great!

Comment: Gordon's #2 is neat, but is it ok to use the query as subquery?